# Attempting to get a javascript variable to be an image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="companyLogo"></div>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var imageName = prompt("Client Logo Image:");
    $('#companyLogo').html(<img src = imageName, style="-webkit-filter: invert(100%);">);
</script>
```

I am trying to get imageName to be the source for the "img src" tag. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i think you can try the same thing in other way, by keeping an img(display:none) in the div and when the user enters image name in the prompt box, then just change the src value of the img and give img css property of Display:block. simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

in the begining :

```
<div id="companyLogo">
  <img src="" id="#companyImg" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

On some event the prompt box is displayed to the user

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var imageName = prompt("Client Logo Image:");
      $("#companyImg").attr('src', 'your image path' + imageName);
      $("#companyImg").css('display','block');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a better practice to keep your javascript away from your html. So you could create an html document like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
    <img id="companyLogo" src="path/to/some/default.img" alt="Your Company Logo" />

 <script>
    //prompts user for input
    var imgSrc = prompt("Please input name");

    //changes src of the targeted image to the value input by the user
    document.getElementById("companyLogo").src = imgSrc;
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69qzcyyo/)

Comment: thanks. I had a separate one, but I didn't feel like switching to it so i just used inline